# Highchart not rendering inside a ajax function angularjs

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

Highchart is not rendering data from the ajax call. If i used outside $http function with static data the highchart is rendering. The high chart is not triggering.

html:

```
  <hc-pie-chart title="Browser usage" data="pieData">Placeholder for pie chart</hc-pie-chart>
```

controller:

```
$scope.homeallpcn = function(){
  var url = "homechartall";
  var data = "";
  $http.get(url).then( function(response) {
    $scope.pieData = [{
                    name: "Cancelled",
                    y: response.c
                }, {
                    name: "Closed",
                    y: response.cl,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                }, {
                    name: "Open",
                    y: response.o
                }, {
                    name: "Rejected",
                    y: response.r
              }]

  });


}
$scope.homeallpcn();
```

service:

```
mainApp.directive('hcPieChart', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<div></div>',
                scope: {
                    title: '@',
                    data: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    Highcharts.chart(element[0], {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'pie'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: scope.title
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            pie: {
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            data: scope.data
                        }]
                    });
                }
            };
        })
```

Please give me suggestion.

Comment: Please create a live demo. If chart is created first and data comes later on then use [series.setData](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData) for dynamic update.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestion :

1 - Do a `console.log(response)` after the call really show the data ?

2 - Remember pie can't works with string data so `response.c`, `response.o` and `response.r` must be integer or float.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Data is coming in response. With static data itself the highchart is not triggering inside ajax call